# Django - Why am I getting TemplateSyntaxError?

Tags: django, django-templates, pinax

I have included a new app [django_colorbox](https://github.com/aljosa/django-colorbox) in my Pinax project. For some reason the following code throw `TemplateSystaxError: Invalid block tag: 'include_colorbox', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock extra_head'`.

```
{% block extra_head %} <!-- Defined in base html template -->
    {% include_colorbox %} <!-- Simple tag defined in django_colorbox -->
{% endblock %}
```

The source code for the errand simple tag is - https://github.com/aljosa/django-colorbox/blob/master/django_colorbox/templatetags/colorbox_tags.py.

If I can embedded other build-in tags (e.g. `blocktrans`) inside `block` then why not the custom simple tags?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to have `{% load colorbox_tags %}` in every template where you use one of the tags.

Comment: TIL. For anybody else coming here from google like I did, this applies just as readily when you want to use `{% static 'somefile' %}`; every template must contain `{% load staticfiles %}` even if it extends a template that already contains that.